# Python 1500% Memory Overhead from loading binary file

Tags: python, memory, io

I'm trying to load one binary file containing 120mb of data using the following routine:

```
from struct import *
def loadBinaryData():
    d = []
    size = calcsize('iif')
    with open("ratings.bin",'rb') as f:
        while True:
            data = f.read(size)
            if not data: break
            (a,b,c) = unpack_from('iif',data)   
            d.append(((a,b),c))
    return d
```

However, when I execute this, my python process starts to use up to 2.2gb of RAM, which - to me - feels very wrong. Are there any obvious errors that can explain this behavior? Am I misusing any very wasteful python features?

One more thing, I don't wanna use generator functions for this, I actually need all of the data in memory.

Comment: If you have numpy, you could read the data into an array using `data = numpy.fromfile('ratings.bin', dtype='i4,i4,f4')`. Since `i4,i4,f4` tells `fromfile` to allocate 4 bytes for each int and float, the memory footprint would remain around 120MB.

Answer (score 2):

I would try converting more data at once, to cut down on per-object memory overhead. Your data seems to be a 3-tuple of around 12 bytes, so for a 120-MB file you have around 10 million tuples.

If you look at [this article](http://www.valuedlessons.com/2008/10/blog-post.html), you can see that:

- An integer has an overhead of 24 bytes.
- A float does, too.
- A tuple has 63 bytes of overhead.

10 million tuples at (2 * 24 + 24 + 63) bytes each is going to weigh in at 1.35 GB, but perhaps there is additional garbage created by the growing of the `d` list.

Comment: @Whadupapp Ah, I mis-interpreted that. It's quite confusing, as written.

Comment: this correctly loads the data. I don't see how reading all data at once with f.read() reduces my memory usage?

Comment: @Whadupapp No, it doesn't, it's probably the actual in-memory format that you arrange the data into that is costly.

Comment: (12+24+24+63+63)/12 = 15.5. this pretty much explains the 1500%. WOW.